# how to get a HTML textbox Value into another HtMl table 

Tags: javascript, html

see.first index.html has a add button..whenever the add button get active it should be add the textbox value into the table.html.The table.html table should be editable and updatable..

pls friends give solution to me.........

Comment: Make your question more clear.

Comment: Assuming you want to save that data permanently, this cannot be done. You'll need more that HTML and JavaScript - you need to run code on a server.

Comment: Data can be stored in cookies or serverside. The question isn't clear... I think that aravind doesn't really knows what he wants...

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but I think that it is not possible to do just by JavaScript !